# Less.js : how to avoid multiple prefix in less file definition ?

Tags: javascript, css, less

For example, I have a html fragment definition as below:

```
<div class="login">
    <div class="header">...</div>
    <div class="content">...</div>
</div>
.......
<div class="home">
    <div class="header">...</div>
    <div class="content">...</div>
</div>
```

I have a less file called login.less, with content as below:

```
.login {
    ....
}

.login .header {
    ....
}

.login .content {
    ....
}
```

As you can see above, every time I add a class under "login" div, I have to write something like `.login .class`, I have to add `.login` before them. Is there any method in less.js to define a base class name so that I don't need to add `.login` everytimes?

Comment: Since you are using Less, nest the rules for child elements within `.login {...}`, that way you wouldn't have to repeat the `.login` in every selector.

Comment: I would suggest re-reading the LESS intro. Nesting is a pretty basic feature.

Comment: Thanks! I am new to less, haven't found this feature.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using *less* you can do as @Harry commented on your question, just nest his children's, on this way, you avoid to repeat the parent selector:

```
.login {
    .header {
        // Code
    }
    .content {
        // Code
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I am new to less, haven't found this feature.